# How to Adjusted Bounce Rate in analytics.js *async

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have tried to search, but can't find the way to set up with analytic.js *async

Original async code

```
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
```

Comment: What you mean? How you are thinking to do to adjusted bounce rate

Comment: https://moz.com/blog/adjusted-bounce-rate

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a session from being considered a bounce, it is necessary that the session send more than one hit to Google Analytics. So if you want a session not to be considered bounce for example after 30 seconds that the user is on a page, you just have to (for example with a setTimeout) send an event to to Google Analytics after 30 seconds.